# Data fetch from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  courses;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    db.list('/courses').valueChanges()
      .subscribe(courses => {
        this.courses = courses;
        console.log(this.courses);
      });
  }
}
```

Expected Behavior:
[Object, Object, Object, Object]

Actual Behavior: 
["course 1", "course 2", {...}, {...}]

The above code returns an array but I expected an array of objects. Also the type returned but the valueChanges() is Observable<{}[]>. I want to know is it the normal behavior of valueChanges() i.e., returning an Observable as object along with an array. Please help me out and tell me where I am wrong in my code. I want an array of objects as an end result with this code.

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your database please?

Comment: I think I found the cause of the actual behavior. I exported the JSON file to my editor and when i see the structure it was a lot different that i expected. It was like below snippet:

**{
  "courses" : [ null, "course1", "course2", {
    "author" : "Mosh Hamedani",
    "price" : 150,
    "title" : "course3"
  } ]
}**

I am new to firebase, so can you please tell me whether the data should be stored in the object oriented format or the format above.
And thank you very much for giving the clue about database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer your question: yes, this is the normal behavior.

Since Firebase is a realtime database, it wants to keep track of any path you've queried and see if it changed ( no matter from where the change came from, you or your user )

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the objects returned afterwards, but since the code is very minor, i would expect you just need to display it in some list with its values ...

So I would write something like this, where you can still access each item in the `Array` like it's an `object`:

```
# course.model.ts
export class courseModel {
    title:  string = "";
    price:  string = "";
    author: string = "";
}

# app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  courses : Observable<courseModel[]> = new courseModel();

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
      this.courses = db.list('/courses').valueChanges();          
  }
}

# app.html
<p *ngFor="let course of courses | async">
 {{ course.title }}
 {{ course.author }}
 {{ course.price }}
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

From https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md

> **valueChanges()**
>
> **What is it?** - Returns an Observable of data as a synchronized array of JSON objects. All Snapshot metadata is stripped and just the method provides only the data.

So instead of getting `[{ key: value }]` you are getting `[value]`.

If you want the full object, including key, use `snapshotChanges()`.
You'll need to import `map` from rxjs/operators for this as well.

```js
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

db.list('/courses').snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(map(snapshots => {
    return snapshots.map(snapshot => {
      let course = {};
      course[snapshot.key] = snapshot.payload.val();
      return course;
    });
  })).subscribe(courses => {
    this.courses = courses;
    console.log(this.courses);
  });
```

This will return an array of users with the structure `[{ key: value }]`. If you want it formatted differently, like `[{ "key": key, "value": value }]`, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: With your code it is showing error on map operator which says "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<AngularFIreAction<DatabaseSnapshot<{}>>[]>'"
I have imported the map operator also.

Comment: Add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` to the top of your file.

Comment: Yeah, i have imported the map operator in the same way as yours.

Comment: Try adding `import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";` as well.

Comment: Now the error is in line snapshot.key on key and in snapshot.payload on payload.

Comment: Sorry for the previous unhelpful answers and suggestions, I never used the `map()` function before (only the `.map` method) so I was just going off of what other people suggested on github posts. Creating a test environment of my own using the same code showed me what I was doing wrong though. Please check my new updated answer.

Comment: Hey, please don't say sorry atleast you have tried to solve the problem and that's a very big help. I will use your new updated answer and let you know if it works or not.

Comment: It worked bro. Thanks for your help. Can you please tell me what is the actual format of the firebase json file. I have searched everywhere but found no results.

Comment: The actual format of which file? Your Firebase Realtime Database JSON tree?

Comment: Yes the database json file.

Comment: If you can see the above discussion with jeremy i have posted the json format that i am seeing as my json file. I want to know is it the correct format or there is something wrong with this.

Comment: Yes, that is a valid JSON object for a Realtime Database. If you're wondering why `courses` was exported as an array of values instead of an object with key value pairs, check out [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) post which explains it well.

Comment: I am wondering why this data is not stored like this inside json 
**{
  "courses": [ {
    "1": "course1",
    "2": "course2",
    "3": {
      "title": "course3",
      "price": "150"
    }
  } ]
}** file imported from firebase.

Comment: From the link I posted in my last comment, "if all of the keys are integers, and more than half of the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty values, then Firebase will render it as an array". The keys go `0, 1, 2`, so firebase renders it like an array.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are a great guy. Is there any way i can contact you in person. I have more problems in which i am great difficulties in understanding them. If you can help me with those and you have time than please share some way to contact you.

Comment: If you have more questions I suggest Googling them, checking SO posts and reading the Firebase documentation first. If you're still having trouble understanding something, you can always ask again on here, show your research effort or some code to reproduce your problem and someone will answer.

Answer (score -1):

It's a simple change and your code is work as it is

And it's worked for me

1. First you need to use data type **any[]** of courses
2. You need to use **subscribe** method instead of directly store **valueChanges()** value into variable
3. Because of  angular older version support  directly **valueChanges()** method to get values but in latest angular version you need to use **subscribe method** and assign value like this.

`courses : any[];`
`constructor(db:AngularFireDatabase){`
`db.list('/courses').valueChanges().subscribe(courses=>`
    `{`
 `this.courses=courses;`
`console.log(this.courses);`
  `});`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your answer to explain how the changes you made to the code fix the problem, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.

Comment: Please have more explanation on your answer if you wish to help others.